# How to get Data From JSON file using Vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I am getting problem in for retrieving data from JSON file using Vue.js .. 
HTML and JSON data and Script is given below ..
please help...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vue with JSON</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>          
  </head>

  <body>
    start 
    <br/>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Data in JSoN</h1>
      <div v-for="udata in userData">
        id:{{ udata.id }} Name: {{ udata.name }}
      </div>
      <h1>End</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
      var dataURL='data.json';
      var App=new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
          userData:[]
        },
        mounted(){
          var self=this
          $.getJSON(dataURL,function(data){
            self.userData=data.users;
          });
        }
      })
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and

JSON file is

```html
{"user":[{"id":"1","name":"jaydeep Gondaliya","email":"jaydeep@live24u.com","phone":"121323232"},{"id":"2","name":"Kelly","email":"kelly@dd.com","phone":"12122322323"}]}
```

i can not getting result .....

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is, just that it's not working

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it's your data. If your response is an object that looks like this (singular `user`)

```
{
  user: [...]
}
```

You're not likely that you'll be able to access it with the plural `users` `elf.userData=data.users;`